# Detect Memory Issues when training a DNN with Tensorflow

Tags: memory, tensorflow, memory-leaks, keras, coredump

I'm currently training a neural network on a sequence of datafiles using keras with tensorflow as backend. More specifically I'm having a generator functions that sequentially reads data from the files and feed it to the fit_generator() function of keras. However, what happens is that after a while it seems tensorflow is exceeding the job memory limit of my machine. What I get is

```
name: GeForce GTX TITAN
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8755
pciBusID 0000:02:00.0
Total memory: 5.94GiB
Free memory: 5.87GiB
2017-08-18 09:05:04.052767: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 
2017-08-18 09:05:04.052784: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y 
2017-08-18 09:05:04.052817: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0)
 500/2136 [======>.......................] - ETA: 778s - loss: 21.8780 - acc: 0.0000e+00   
 RAM Usage 1.01 GB 


 706/2136 [========>.....................] - ETA: 679s - loss: 16.7906 - acc: 0.0000e+00as 
 Read File Number 2 

1000/2136 [=============>................] - ETA: 539s - loss: 13.1006 - acc: 0.0000e+00 
 RAM Usage 1.01 GB 


1421/2136 [==================>...........] - ETA: 336s - loss: 10.4089 - acc: 0.0000e+00srun: Exceeded job memory limit
```

As for now I print the RAM usage using the resource package and

```
print(' \n RAM Usage {:.2f} GB \n \n'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss/1e6))
```

I also used the memory profiler at it seems that RAM usage is not increasing at all. I'm pretty sure it not the fit_generator making the 
problem since the problem also occurs with the most simple generator I could think of

```
batch_input = np.zeros((batch_size,20,10,60,1))
batch_out = np.zeros((batch_size,1))
    while True:
        yield (batch_input, batch_out)
```

Anyone having an idea what else I could check in order to tackle this problem? Might this be a problem of the GPU drivers of the system I'm working on?

Note that the same code runs smoothly if I use the Theano backend.

And not sure if this is related: But another think i noticed is, that if i reduce the number of files to be read I don't exceed the memory limit, but after finishing one epoche of training the core just dumps with a segementation fault.

```
name: GeForce GTX TITAN
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8755
pciBusID 0000:02:00.0
Total memory: 5.94GiB
Free memory: 5.87GiB
2017-08-18 08:55:45.345022: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 
2017-08-18 08:55:45.345039: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y 
2017-08-18 08:55:45.345062: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0)
500/706 [====================>.........] - ETA: 98s - loss: 4.0806 - acc: 0.0000e+00   
 RAM Usage 1.01 GB 


705/706 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.9775 - acc: 0.0000e+00Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Sorry for this question being a bit long. Hope some can give me a hint of how to search for solutions for these kinds of memory errors.

Thanks :)

Comment: upgrading tensorflow would help,

Comment: unfortunately upgrading did not help. running tensorflow-gpu 1.3.0 but the problem still exists

Comment: Did you try decreasing the `max_queue_size`?